# How Does the Office Communicator Presence Status Work?

Tags: office-communicator, user-presence

I'm interested in finding out more about the [Microsoft Office Communicator](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/communicator/default.aspx) IM client, and how it determines your presence (i.e if you are at your computer or away).  Can anyone point me towards a tutorial that explains this, or details of the API?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After a bit of research, it looks like the Office Communicator client makes use of a simple audit of keyboard and mouse activity to determine the presence of a user.  This article discusses the [Microsoft Communicator presence status](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/help/HA102067221033.aspx), and these related questions also refer to it:

- https://superuser.com/questions/21364/how-do-i-detect-when-a-user-is-sitting-in-the-chair-in-front-of-a-computer/21380#21380
- [Detecting user presence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014392/detecting-user-presence)

It appears that Office Communicator makes use of the Windows API [GetLastInputInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646302%28VS.85%29.aspx) Function.
The following questions detail the options for calling this function (with and without P/Invoke):

- [.NET equivalent for GetLastInputInfo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069910/net-equivalent-for-getlastinputinfo)
- [C# - Detect time of last user interaction with the OS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1037595/c-detect-time-of-last-user-interaction-with-the-os)

Comment: How sad, thought that someone would come along and improve on this.  Accepting my own answer (until someone posts a better answer).