# COM Exception trying to get Presence from Office Communicator 2007

Tags: exception, com, exchange-server, ocs, office-communicator

I am building a proof of concept on a new box that has been set up with Windows Server Standard running IIS 7.

The task I need to do is take the logged in user and using Office Communicator 2007 check for the presence (and type of presence, online, offline, away, busy etc) of other users on the exchange box on the same machine.

The code seems pretty simple:

```
public string GetStatus(string username)
    {
        try
        {
            if(this.CurrentCommunicator == null)
                this.CurrentCommunicator = new CommunicatorAPI.MessengerClass();

            this.CurrentCommunicator.Signin(0, "********", "*****");

            if (CurrentCommunicator != null)
            {
                foreach (IMessengerContact contact in CurrentCommunicator.MyContacts as IMessengerContacts)
                {
                    if (!contact.IsSelf)
                        if (contact.SigninName.Contains(username))
                        {
                            MISTATUS status = contact.Status;
                            return GetStatusString(status);
                        }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return ex.Message;
        }
        return "Unknown";
    }
```

I am logged into Office Communicator 2007 with the correct u/p so OCS instantiates, but when the code attempts to loop round the Contacts:

```
foreach (IMessengerContact contact in CurrentCommunicator.MyContacts as IMessengerContacts)
```

it throws this error:

Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {8885370D-B33E-44B7-875D-28E403CF9270} failed due to the following error: 80070005.

[Chris Crowe's blog](https://web.archive.org/web/20130515210838/http://blog.crowe.co.nz/archive/2006/03/02/589.aspx) seemed to offer a way forward but after changing the launch and activation permissions of 'Office Communicator Messenger Class' so that 'Network Service' had local launch activation rights - there was no change in the COM error that was being thrown.

I've also tried giving 'Everyone' launch and activation permissions with no change.

---

I've read through a slew of OCS articles, but I can't seem to solve this problem.  Please help before I wrench out more clumps of hair.

How can I write my own C# program for login in Office Communicator
http://www.mombu.com/microsoft/live-communications-server-developer/t-how-i-can-write-my-own-c-program-for-login-in-office-comunicator-927275.html

How to get presence using office communicator sdk
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cmayo/archive/2009/09/21/how-to-get-presence-using-office-communicator-sdk.aspx

The Office Communicator Automation API in 2 minutes
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cmayo/archive/2009/01/08/the-office-communicator-automation-api-in-2-min.aspx

Using the Office Communicator Automation API
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/midunn/archive/2008/03/09/using-the-communicator-automation-api.aspx

Building a custom contact list in Office Communicator
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb758709(v=office.12).aspx

How Does the Office Communicator Presence Status Work?
[How Does the Office Communicator Presence Status Work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2506961/how-does-the-office-communicator-presence-status-work)

Detecting user presence
[Detecting user presence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014392/detecting-user-presence)

Configuration Information for OWA 2010 Form Authentication
http://www.stone-ware.com/cloud/support/3rdPartyDetails.jsp?id=216

Getting Started Using Office Communicator Automation API
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb758820(office.12).aspx

Office Communicator 2007 Development Environments For .NET Framework Applications
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb787231(v=office.12).aspx

Event ID 56013 with an error code of 80070005 is logged in Event Viewer when you change the password for Office Communications Server 2007 service accounts
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/953112/en-us

Fixing Office COM 80070005 errors by changing 'Launch and Activation' permissions
http://blog.crowe.co.nz/archive/2006/03/02/589.aspx

Sign into Communicator (Office Communicator 2007)
http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/communicator-help/sign-in-to-communicator-HA010206469.aspx?redir=0

AutoLogin into OCS API example
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ucclientsdk/thread/bc0ba921-7cc5-4098-b137-ffb85d667e58

Office 2007 - Interface Member Invocations
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb758725(v=office.12).aspx

Comment: Is this running in a web page? If so, have you tried the same code, but running in a WinForms app on the server? Is the Communicator SDK definitely installed on the server?

Comment: @Paul, a workaround was developed by the network guys making some server changes to enable Active Directory to automatically login - I then used a different Lynv method (GetContactByUri) to achieve the presence indication.